# Can not check fill state properly on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

On my WPF I have a rectangle with default: `Fill="#3E7A61"`

The color can be changed with:

```
private SolidColorBrush CustomRed = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#95305D");
private SolidColorBrush CustomGreen = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#3E7A61");
private int ClickCount = 0;

    public void RMaximize_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ClickCount++;
        RMaximize.Fill = (ClickCount % 2 == 1) ? CustomGreen : CustomRed;
    }
```

How can I check if the default value is `CustomGreen`? I tried:

```
            if (RMaximize.Fill == CustomGreen) // Or #3E7A61
            {
                Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            }
```

But it did not work.

Comment: `((SolidColorBrush)RMaximize.Fill).Color == CustomGreen.Color` should work.

Comment: It did, thank you!